# How to update expires field to today + 1 year

Tags: expiration

I have a list of deadlines for Tax forms. These deadlines will be the same each year.
What I am trying to do is add a retention stage to say "When the expiry date is today" run a workflow. The workflow needs to update this expiry field to today + 1 year. 
I know how to update the field, but the only two options it seems to offer me is current date, or a specific date which I would enter.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a workflow variable and add it to an action to do this. Its 2007 but Point 4 in this article should show you the way. http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sample-sharepoint-workflows/4-ways-set-date-value-sharepoint-designer-workflow.htm

For more info on workflow variables/actions look here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx

Comment: Oh dear. School boy error! Thanks so much or your help. Works like a charm.